# shopping cart using codeigniter cart library and try to integrate with pay you money

Tags: codeigniter, shopping-cart, payumoney

i'm developing a shopping cart using codeigniter cart library and try to integrate with pay you money payment gate way. my question should i store cart session values in database before i'm redirect to pay you money payment website or should i store it in database after i redirect to success url after successfully completed the payment

Answer (score -1):

Since you are not able do so, make sure you are using drumstick.

Comment: Please post more extensive answers. Although sometimes one sentence can help many people *most of the time* in-depth and detailed answers are the most popular.